# Regex: parsing the link that doesn't contain img in anchor

Tags: php, regex, parsing, preg-match, regular-language

I am trying to parse a normal link, but sometimes along with that link there's a similar one that instead of text contains an image.

I have been using this pattern: `"#_blank\">(.*?)</a>#is`, but this also matches the links that contains images in the anchor.

**How could I parse only the ones that doesn't contain image?**

Comment: Can you post some sample html to match please?

Comment: You should a) offer more specific information (e.g. which input is not working) and b) use a HTML parser.

Comment: Please post the code relevant to the question. You can do so by editing your own question, and adding it there, in the body of the question. It will help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<a href=".*?">(?!<img.*?>).*?</a>`

http://regexr.com?30n1q

How about this?

Comment: What if there's a class before the href? what if the href is in caps? What if there's a space between the closing quote of the href and the closing bracket?

Comment: @HappyTimeGopher No need to be so defensive.  He didn't even make such specific requirements.

Comment: just trying to make the point. Often when someone posts a question they're not aware of all the ramifications, so they can't ask about edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any tags matched inside your a tag, try this to get the inner html from all a tags on the page:

```
#<a [^>]+>([^<]+)</a>#si
```

In light of your comment...

What I'd probably do to avoid a monster regex, is use the above then do this:

```
$output = strip_tags( $match[1], '<b><i><u>' );
```

Add other allowable tags to taste. This approach also ensures there's no nasty tags in the final string.

Comment: Only images, i dont care if there is bold or other tags like that, i guess your pattern could be tweaked, I'll try but Im not very good at regex.